# Why does my "hosts" file entry have no effect when accessing network shares?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, localhost, hosts-file

I added the following line to a Windows7 `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 mecserver
```

Using `ping mecserver` works fine, but if I use this name to connect to the notebook (like localhost) to see the Windows shares it always wants me to enter user credentials. Entering the local username + password doesn't work. Which indicates to me that the remote host is connected.

Using the following in the Windows explorer address field of local system results in:

`\\mecserver`
**Result**: I have to enter a username and password but the local user don't work

`\\localhost`
**Result**: Displays me the local shares - this is what I want with `\\mecserver`

`\\127.0.0.1`
**Result**: Displays me the local shares - this is what I want with `\\mecserver`

I want to use `\\mecserver` with the result of `localhost`/`127.0.0.1`. Is this somehow possible?

EDIT: What I have done so far:

I shared on a Notebook a network share with the name "testshare". Without any network cable/wlan connected I try to connect to this share from this notebook. This works with *\localhost\testshare* and *\127.0.0.1\testshare*. But I need a special path for a third party program like *\mecserver\testshare*. So I added the line *127.0.0.1 mecserver* to the host file. *ping mecserver* works (local from this notebook) but when I try to access the testshare with *\mecserver\testshare* it promts a login window. I entered the current notebook user but it says password wrong. I even added a new testuser with the name test and password test and tried to add this into this login window but it don't work (password wrong). Enabling the guest account don't help either. The share is open to everyone and the file/directory security access for this folder/files too.

Adding *127.0.0.1 mecserver* to the lmhosts file has the same effect like adding to the hosts file - it promts me this login window. I removed the *127.0.0.1 mecserver* line from the hosts file when I played with the lmhosts file just to be sure.

[image: Login dialog window (sorry only in german)]

Comment: I **think** the `hosts` file only affects DNS lookups (which is why `ping`works). When you use the double-backslash to access network shares, WINS/NetBIOS is used.

Comment: Possibly related: http://serverfault.com/a/42916/61246

Comment: I changed the registry values and restarted the computer but it did not change anything.

Comment: The user local _to where_?  The client?  Or the server providing the file service?

Comment: I added a more detailed description what I have tried.

Comment: I had the same problem. Here is solution:
http://serverfault.com/questions/23823/how-to-configure-windows-machine-to-allow-file-sharing-with-dns-alias

Answer (score 10):

I think you need to look at the `LMHOSTS` file. The `hosts` file seems to only affect generic DNS lookups. When you use the `\\` to access a network share, WINS is used.

In the same folder where you find the `hosts` file, there should also be a `lmhosts` file.

The contents sound promising:

```
# This is a sample LMHOSTS file used by the Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to computernames
# (NetBIOS) names.  Each entry should be kept on an individual line.
# The IP address should be placed in the first column followed by the
# corresponding computername. The address and the computername
# should be separated by at least one space or tab. The "#" character
# is generally used to denote the start of a comment (see the exceptions
# below).
```

There is also a Wikipedia article on [LMHOSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LMHOSTS).

---

Also, please note this section in the Advanced TCP/IP settings for your given network connection:

[image: Advanced TCP/IP Settings]

I would assume the checkbox **has** to be checked for the `lmhosts` file to be respected. Also, if editing the `lmhosts` file directly does not yield the desired result, I would attempt using that "Import LMHOSTS" functionality.

---

**Update** I'm confident that, in general, this is the right approach to the issue. If I create a copy of the `lmhosts.sam` file and add a new line at the end:

```
127.0.0.1 mecserver
```

I then have to use the "Import LMHOSTS..." functionality (which creates the `lmhosts` file). I can then browse to `\\mecserver` and am asked for credentials (like you describe). Without the change in `lmhosts` I had gotten an error telling me the machine is non-existent.

I can't shake the feeling that this manipulation has a negative impact on the general authentication process of Windows, because, as you describe, no otherwise valid login works on the presented prompt. However, this might be a new problem, which should be asked in a new question.

Comment: I removed the entry from hosts file and added 127.0.0.1 mecserver to the lmhosts.sam file directly. Result: computername not known
Now I copied the lmhosts.sam file to another folder and imported it like you described above - the computername mecserver is now known again but I have to enter a user login (like with the hosts solution) but no known user login works

Comment: I added another user to the laptop (username: test password: test) and entered this into the dialogbox. It recognizes the account picture of the local test account but it always says unknown username or wrong password.

Comment: The `lmhosts.sam` file seems to be an example file. I think you need to use that as a template and then use the Import LMHOSTS functionality.

Comment: Yeah I did this too but no success.

Comment: I wonder if [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/23823/how-to-configure-windows-machine-to-allow-file-sharing-with-dns-alias) is related. I'm getting some weird behavior here that I'm having a hard time understanding myself. Like, try to connect to `\\127.0.0.2` it gives me the login dialog as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions issue. The user that you are trying to use to access the share is not allowed to access the share.
You need to add /mecserver/yourusername to the allowed users list for the share.
Maybe it could also work if you check the "Everyone" entry in the users list when you create the share.