# Wifi and LAN on same computer

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have a laptop with Windows 7 installed. Its connected to my office LAN with following IP scheme. I use multiple network based portals over WAN. Internet is not available on this ethernet based connection.

```
IP: 10.44.99.193
MASK: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 10.44.99.1
DNS1: 10.7.109.1
DNS2: 10.7.109.2
```

I have a WiFi connection with following configuration, which provides internet.

```
IP: DHCP (192.168.1.100~200)
Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
DSN: 8.8.8.8
DSN: 8.8.4.4
```

**Problem:** If the Wifi is disconnected, i can use all my LAN based services but as soon I connect WiFi the LAN stops to respond and even i can't ping my WAN (headoffice) ips (10.x.x.x).
**Already Tested**: I have assigned matrics 1 & 2 respectively to LAN & Wifi but no luck.
**Required**: I need to use internet on this laptop, without disturbing my LAN applications, e.g. MS Exchange based email, WAN based webportals, ... etc.

Comment: Are you at the office, when you encounter the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a route via the following command:

> ROUTE -p ADD 10.44.99.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.44.99.1 IF 1

if your LAN interface has number 1 (see `ROUTE PRINT` for the list of interfaces)
Some laptops just switch off wifi when ethernet cable is plugged in, so check if it is your case.
Also metrics on Wifi connection should be lower than on LAN connection.

But your problem is DNS server. You need to access your local network services (i.e. exchange server...) by name and that is the problem.

You may try to setup your wifi to use company DNS1: 10.7.109.1. Perhaps your company's DNS is setup to translate public names. Or you will have to enter your intranet names manually using LMHosts file as [described here](https://superuser.com/a/387022/285900) while using Google's DNS 8.8.8.8.

But what you are trying to achieve is not good and possibly breaking company policies, you should have company internet's connection within LAN and behind the firewall.